# Send response in json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hashmap, rails-api

I have model of category . I want to send response like this

```
{"1":"Food",2:"Clothes",3:"Shoes"}
```

I tried

```
Category.all.map{ |k| { k.id.to_i => k.name  } }
```

But it send like this

```
[{"1": "Engineer"},{"2": "Doctor"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
Category.all.reduce({}) { |memo, obj| memo.merge(obj.id.to_s => obj.name) }
```